# OneLogin - OIDC - Implicit Flow - login_hint

Tags: onelogin

Does anyone know if there is a workaround for OneLogin's lack of support of the login_hint parameter during the OIDC implicit flow request?

My main goal is to be able to pre-populate the username/email of the login page.

https://{subdomain}.onelogin.com/login

The redirect generated by the implicit flow requests to the login page does not include the hint information.  The login form does however load the email address of the user the last sign in successfully, which is great, but not the best experience for first sign in.

I also noticed that you can pre-populate the mail address directly by calling the login page directly and provide an email query string parameter, however this does not meet our need.

https://{subdomain}.onelogin.com/login?email=user@example.com

Answer (score 1):

I received confirmation from the OneLogin support team that the login_hint query parameter is not currently supported, but may add it in the future.

Comment: For information to others:

Using the Authorization Flow, login_hint is supported. The email must be matching a account record in OneLogin for it to prefill the Username field.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `login_hint` to `$parameters` params:

```
$auth->login(null, array('login_hint' => $email));
```